# Bring local site to live site url not working

Tags: php, html, mysql, css, drupal-7

I have developed a site using **drupal 7**. I have moved my site from local server to live server.
But the **live Url not opening** my sites **index** page. For example, my web site address is http://test.com. But if i change the URL like http://test.com/2index.php it works well. Somebody help me please

Answer (score 0):

File name should be `index.php` not `2index.php`.

Answer (score 0):

I agree the that file name should be index.php, however if there is some reason why the name must be 2index.php and you want it to serve as an index, you need to modify your apache config file to include "2index.php" as one the options for the "DirectoryIndex".  The config line may look like this:

DirectoryIndex index.php index.phtml index.html index.htm 2index.php